# omission of should in that clause

Tags: subjunctive-mood, should

I know that the following sentences are both correct with and without "should."

1. It is strange that he should be angry.
2. It is strange that he be angry.

How about these?

3. It is strange that he should have failed.
4. It is strange that he have failed.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: No, only version (3) is correct this time. It may help to re-order: (3') That he should have failed is strange. / (4') *That he have failed is strange.

Comment: (3) is valid but awkward. (4) is not grammatical. You could also say "It is strange that he has failed." or "It is strange that he failed."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. By using the indicative mood, you say like "It is strange that he has failed./It is strange that he failed," I see. I am wondering about the usage of the subjunctive mood in a case like 4. From your answers, I assume that it is obsolete, but in theory, how would that be?

Comment: The mandative subjunctive is not obsolete. It is used after adjectives that express requirements or recommendations, etc. in impersonal constructions. For example, _It is important that he be on time_. I don't recall seeing it with adjectives such as _strange_ or _interesting_: ? _It is strange that he be angry_ - and certainly not with verbs other than _to be_: ?? _It is strange that he have failed_. The mandative subjunctive is usually paraphrased with _should_ in British English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It is strange that he be angry* is an archaic use of the "present subjunctive" which is rare in modern English, and almost obsolete in this context.

*It is strange that he have failed* is parallel: a present subjunctive, which was presumably grammatical at one time; but unlike occasional instances of *be*, I don't think most people would even recognise it as an archaism.

Comment: I'd star them both. The present subjunctive in an extraposed subject after _strange_ is totally weird.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Fine, for clearing this up for me! Also, thank you very much everyone for your valuable information.